# PostGIS raster - sum of rasters

Tags: postgis, raster, postgis-raster

I have raster data stored in a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database. I need to create a summed raster from certain rasters.

Something like:

```
select sum(raw_data) as image from data where rid > 2 AND rid < 5;
```

But this is not the correct function. What is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [ST_Union](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Union.html)(rast, 'SUM')

Overlapping pixels will be summed into a new raster. Note there are also FIRST, MIN, MAX, COUNT, MEAN, RANGE  options for the uniontype paramter.

Comment: Good to know. There was me thinking  you needed MapAlgebra, hugely overcomplicating things as always.